# Show that $(1+A)^{\alpha}\leq 1+A^{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Motivated by the proof of [Proposition 4.6](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870813003575#se0040). The question is, if $A\geq 0$ and $\alpha\in (0,1]$, how would you show mathematically that $(1+A)^{\alpha}\leq 1+A^{\alpha}$? If I put $f_\alpha(A):=(1+A)^{\alpha}/(1+A^\alpha)$, and then find its derivative to find out when it is decreasing, it takes time. I tried to look at Bernoulli's inequality, it has no connection to it. What to do?

Comment: Maybe the binomial theorem? There might be a way to extend that to subsets of the real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your idea, differentiate $f(A)=(1+A)^\alpha - (1+A^\alpha)$ would work.

Comment: Much easier than my answear

Answer (score 2):

Is the same as showing $1+A\ \le\ \left(1+A^{\alpha}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ consider de function $f\left(\alpha\right)=\ \left(1+A^{\alpha}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ from $(0,1]$ is easy to see $f(1)=1+A$ and then derive to show that $f$ is decreasing between $0$ and $1$